# How to prevent Chrome 12 trying to use Helvetica Neue when it isn't installed

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, fonts

This is what I see when I view a website using Helvetica Neue in Chrome 12.

[image]

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit, and IE9 and FF5 both render the text <strike>differently</strike> readable (using the next font in the CSS stack).

I've checked my Fonts folder (C:\Windows\Fonts) and I can't see any version of Helvetica anywhere.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It seems the problem is **not** preventing Helvetica Neue (because it **isn't** installed, anyway) but making IE9 and FF5 use the same font instead. Doesn't the font stack apply to *both*?

Comment: @pavium, except that if IE9 and FF5 did what Chrome does then I wouldn't be able to read sites using Helvetica in any browser.

Comment: @Jon Helvetica looks unreadable anyway even if displayed correctly. It is a display typeface, not designed for running text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Helvetica was installed, but Windows wasn't showing it in the Fonts folder.

I used FontExpert to track it down and remove it and that seems to have fixed things.

Comment: Jon, how did you get this to stick? I've used FontExpert to remove HelveticaNeue (not Helvetica itself), but TweetDeck is still showing up with the same garbage characters you had. Should I remove Helvetica, as well? Any other thoughts?

Comment: @JoshSamBob not sure I'm afraid, might be worth a shot!

Answer (score 3):

I can't see your screenshot.

Chrome should use another font, which is set in the CSS, or which is set in the browser settings. The CSS should work for all browsers the same, although a (not so?) clever css-developer might want to use alternate css for different browsers.

In Chrome, click on the wrench-icon right next to the address bar, choose preferences, then choose "under the hood", web content > customize fonts. There you can set which font you want to see as standard serif/sans-serif or mono font.

Comment: I reupped the screenshot, you should be able to see it.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for updating the screenshot. I understand that Chrome should use another font - what I don't understand is why it isnt doing that. The customized font settings are Times New Roman and Arial (which Chrome has no problem rendering). My encoding is set to Western ISO-8859-1 if that makes any difference...